# Jackson JSON parsing enum value

Tags: java, json, enums, jackson

Let's say I have an enum class as below:

```
public enum Lang {

    ENGLISH("en_US"), FRENCH("fr_CA");

    String val;

    Lang(String val) {
       this.val = val;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return val;
    }
}
```

And I have a POJO as follows:

```
public class Foo {

    private String bar;
    private Lang lang;


    public String getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar(String bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    public Lang getLang() {
        return lang;
    }

    public void setLang(Lang lang) {
        this.lang = lang;
    }
}
```

How do I configure Jackson to convert the following payload to the POJO class?

{ "bar": "someValue", "lang": "en-US"}

If I use any other string other than "en-US" or "fr-CA", then Jackson needs to reject it.

When I have something like the following, what I see is:

```
{"bar":"bar","lang":"ENGLISH"}



Foo f = new Foo();
        f.setBar("bar");
        f.setLang(Lang.ENGLISH);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(f);
        System.out.println(json);
```

I do not want any text other than "en-US" or whatever I define in the enum class.
How do I customize Jackson to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the following code/annotations:

```
@JsonFormat
public enum Lang {

    ENGLISH("en_US"), 
    FRENCH("fr_CA");

    private String val;

    Lang(String val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    @JsonValue
    public String getValue() {
        return val;
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static Lang fromValue(String value) {
        // TODO return the Lang with the given value, or throw an IllegalArgumentException
    }
}
```